# If f(z) has a branch point at z=0, what does 1/f(z) have at z=0?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, branch-points

If f(z) has a pole of order n at z=0 then 1/f(z) has a zero of order n at z=0. Is there an equivalent for if f(z) has a branch point at z=0 instead? If f(z) has a branch point at z=0, what does 1/f(z) have at z=0?

Comment: I believe we say that both $z^{1/2}$ and $z^{-1/2}$ have branch points at $z=0$.

Comment: note that $1/f$ may not have an isolated singularity at $0$ in general (see something like $(e^{1/z^2}-1)\log z$